# Trying to catch a SQLiteConstraintException in Android Room and display an alert

Tags: android, android-room

I am using a foreign key constraint of `onDelete RESTRICT` so that when the parent has children with the FK it cannot be deleted. This is working correctly.  However I need to alert the user when the `SQLiteConstraintException` is thrown and am using a try-catch-finally block to do that.  However I never get it to enter the catch block and no alert is triggered.  The exception is also causing a runtime crash, so it needs to be handled in some fashion.

I have tried to broaden the exception by using `SQLiteException` and `SQLException` but it still does not work, despite getting the `android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed (code 1811 SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_TRIGGER)`

The delete is triggered in a menu with a switch statement:

```
switch (item.getItemId()) {
...
case R.id.delete_term:
                try{
                    mViewModel.deleteTerm();


                }catch (SQLiteConstraintException ex){
                    AlertDialog.Builder a_builder = new 
                    AlertDialog.Builder(TermEditorActivity.this);
                    a_builder.setMessage("Courses are assigned for this term 
                    and it cannot be deleted." +
                    "\n\nYou must remove all courses prior to deleting a 
                     term.")
                            .setCancelable(false)
                            .setPositiveButton("Okay", new 
                            DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, 
                                int which) {
                                    dialog.cancel();
                                    finish();
                                }
                            });
                    AlertDialog deleteAllAlert = a_builder.create();
                    deleteAllAlert.setTitle("CANNOT DELETE TERM!!!");
                    deleteAllAlert.show();

                }finally {
                    startActivity(new Intent(TermEditorActivity.this, 
                    MainActivity.class));
                }
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
```

Crash log:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed (code 1811 SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_TRIGGER)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForChangedRowCount(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForChangedRowCount(SQLiteConnection.java:784)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForChangedRowCount(SQLiteSession.java:754)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeUpdateDelete(SQLiteStatement.java:64)
        at android.arch.persistence.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteStatement.executeUpdateDelete(FrameworkSQLiteStatement.java:45)
        at android.arch.persistence.room.EntityDeletionOrUpdateAdapter.handle(EntityDeletionOrUpdateAdapter.java:70)
        at com.mattspriggs.termtest.database.TermDao_Impl.deleteTerm(TermDao_Impl.java:144)
        at com.mattspriggs.termtest.database.AppRepository$4.run(AppRepository.java:83)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Method from AppRepository line 83:

```
termDb.termDao().deleteTerm(term);
```

Method deleteTerm from TermDAO:

```
@Delete
    void deleteTerm(TermEntity termEntity);
```

I am hoping to catch the exception and send the use back to the edit screen where they were trying to delete the term.  So far this is not working as intended.  Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score -1):

[RESTRICT documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/ForeignKey.html#RESTRICT)In reading the documentation on RESTRICT, it causes an immediate error and not an exception.  It appears that SQLite Errors are not able to be caught(?) in a try-catch statement? Are they considered serious errors?  I think I will need to query for the presence of any children before allowing the deletion.  However I cannot get back a count of items from a simple query so is my query process incorrect? According to the [Callable](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Callable) documentation, Runnable cannot return a value, so that is why I could not get a count from the DB query.

The way I resolved this was to take a totally different approach.  I placed a recyclerView to an earlier activity and was able to capture the number of children (and display those children in the view) and send it to the editor activity where the deletion takes place and process the deletion via an if-then statement instead of catching the exception.  I was never able to catch the exception.  All I can figure out is that it is an exception within Android but an error in SQLite?

If anyone figures out how to catch the SQLiteConstraintException I would love to know.

Comment: what your saying is impossible because this is an exception and it can be caught. what is happening is that the exception is not being thrown or another exception is being thrown that you are not catching .  also when you refer to a document put a link to it.

Comment: Added the documentation, sorry for then oversight.  "... RESTRICT action processing happens as soon as the field is updated - not at the end of the current statement as it would with an immediate constraint, or at the end of the current transaction as it would with a deferred() constraint.

Even if the foreign key constraint it is attached to is deferred(), configuring a RESTRICT action causes SQLite to return an error immediately if a parent key with dependent child keys is deleted or modified."